# Parsing XML, searching for a target start <row> tag, and ignoring all <row> tags above it

Tags: python, xml, pandas, xml-parsing

I am parsing an XML file into a pandas dataframe. Using the code below I can get it all successfully, however this used an edited version of the full XML.  The full XML has a bunch of summary data on top of the main data table, see full XML [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/plvlfj4avpodxfw/cortex_full.xml?dl=0). The row I need to start extracting is at line 641 in the XML.

**Example of the XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<Styles> ### approx. 300 lines of styling ### </Styles>
<Worksheet ss:Name="MetasoftStudio">
  <Table>
    <Row/>
    <Row>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableTitle" ss:MergeAcross="1"><Data ss:Type="String">CPET Results</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row/>
    <Row>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterName" ss:MergeAcross="1"><Data ss:Type="String">Operator</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterValue" ss:MergeAcross="7"><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row/>
    <Row/>
    <Row>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableTitle" ss:MergeAcross="1"><Data ss:Type="String">Patient data</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row/>
    <Row>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableTitle" ss:MergeAcross="1"><Data ss:Type="String">Administrative Data</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterName" ss:MergeAcross="1"><Data ss:Type="String">ID</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterValue" ss:MergeAcross="7"><Data ss:Type="String">B013</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterName" ss:MergeAcross="1"><Data ss:Type="String">Title</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterValue" ss:MergeAcross="7"><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterName" ss:MergeAcross="1"><Data ss:Type="String">Last Name</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterValue" ss:MergeAcross="7"><Data ss:Type="String">Data</Data></Cell>
    </Row>

### Skipping few hundred lines ###

    <Row>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">Variable</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">Unit</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">Rest</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">Warm Up</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">AT</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">AT % Max</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">RCP</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">RCP % Max</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">V'O2peak</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">Absolute Maximum Values</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableParameters"><Data ss:Type="String">V'O2</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableUnits"><Data ss:Type="String">L/min</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableValues"><Data ss:Type="String">0.34</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableValues"><Data ss:Type="String">-</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableValues"><Data ss:Type="String">1.83</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableValues"><Data ss:Type="String">76</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableValues"><Data ss:Type="String">2.28</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableValues"><Data ss:Type="String">94</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableValues"><Data ss:Type="String">2.42</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableValues"><Data ss:Type="String">2.59</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
### Skipping some more lines ###
    <Row>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableParameters"><Data ss:Type="String">Borg</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableUnits"><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableValues"><Data ss:Type="String">-</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableValues"><Data ss:Type="String">-</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableValues"><Data ss:Type="String">-</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableValues"><Data ss:Type="String">-</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableValues"><Data ss:Type="String">-</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableValues"><Data ss:Type="String">-</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableValues"><Data ss:Type="String">-</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="SummaryTableValues"><Data ss:Type="String">-</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row/>
    <Row/>
###### NEED TO START EXTRACTING FROM THIS ROW ######
    <Row>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="MeasurementDataTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">t</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="MeasurementDataTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">Phase</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="MeasurementDataTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">Marker</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="MeasurementDataTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">V'O2</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="MeasurementDataTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">V'CO2</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="MeasurementDataTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">V'E</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="MeasurementDataTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">V'E/V'O2</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="MeasurementDataTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">V'E/V'CO2</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="MeasurementDataTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">HR</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="MeasurementDataTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">RER</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="MeasurementDataTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">V'O2/kg</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="MeasurementDataTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">PetO2</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="MeasurementDataTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">PetCO2</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="MeasurementDataTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">ExCO2</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="MeasurementDataTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">BF</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="MeasurementDataTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">WR</Data></Cell>
      <Cell ss:StyleID="MeasurementDataTableHead"><Data ss:Type="String">Borg</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
### XML File continues the same from here with the same structure ###
```

**My current code:**

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd

with open('cortex.xml', 'r') as infile:
    root = etree.parse(infile)

namespaces = {'o': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office',
              'x': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel',
              'ss': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'}

data = []

ws = root.xpath('/ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet', namespaces=namespaces)
if len(ws) > 0:
    tables = ws[0].xpath('./ss:Table', namespaces=namespaces)
    if len(tables) > 0:
        rows = tables[0].xpath('./ss:Row', namespaces=namespaces)
        for row in rows:
            temp = []
            cells = row.xpath('./ss:Cell/ss:Data', namespaces=namespaces)
            for cell in cells:
                temp.append(cell.text)
            data.append(temp)

df = pd.DataFrame(data[2:], columns=data[0])
```

How would I need to edit my current code to only extract data corresponding to the `<Row>` tags in the main data table? The amount of summary data on top can vary so hard coding a starting point isn't an option.

The `<Cell>` in the first `<Row>` of the main data have an attribute `StyleID="MeasurementDataTableHead"`, is it possible to base a search on that and start extraction from there? I am completely stumped on this one.

Comment: If open `xml` file in `MS excel` there are 6 different tables. If change code in question to `df = pd.DataFrame(data)` get all tables together (not nice output). Parsing data is not easy - my idea is split tables by first row if empty. Is it possible? Or need parse not all tables?

Comment: I only need the last big table at the bottom of the file (starting row 70 if opened in `ms excel` or line  641 if opened in `text editor`) - not anything above it. The difficult part is that all the tables sit under the same `<Table>` tag inside the `XML` code. I'm not sure how to split each based on an empty row - I assume a combination of for and if loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If parsed table is always last you can create helper boolean, set to `True` if value `t` (first value of parsed table) and append by it:

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd

with open('cortex_full.xml', 'r') as infile:
    root = etree.parse(infile)

namespaces = {'o': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office',
              'x': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel',
              'ss': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'}

data = []
parse = False
ws = root.xpath('/ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet', namespaces=namespaces)
if len(ws) > 0:
    tables = ws[0].xpath('./ss:Table', namespaces=namespaces)
    if len(tables) > 0:
        rows = tables[0].xpath('./ss:Row', namespaces=namespaces)
        for row in rows:
            temp = []
            cells = row.xpath('./ss:Cell/ss:Data', namespaces=namespaces)
            for cell in cells:
                if cell.text == 't':
                    parse = True
                if parse:    
                    temp.append(cell.text)
            if parse:  
                data.append(temp)
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data[2:], columns=data[0])
print (df.head())

         t Phase Marker               V'O2              V'CO2  \
0  0:00:10  Rest   None  0.251524741119069  0.236014510176694   
1  0:00:20  Rest   None  0.434384403499744  0.411231246288168   
2  0:00:30  Rest   None  0.343945761508378  0.341020990667946   
3  0:00:40  Rest   None  0.220729503668137  0.196421701276079   
4  0:00:50  Rest   None  0.257787497144625  0.217026849651075   

                V'E          V'E/V'O2         V'E/V'CO2 HR                RER  \
0          11.89836  36.3356700392092  38.7235513323219  0  0.938335167851211   
1          15.59965  31.7517155056147  33.5394017952007  0  0.946698921450597   
2  14.8086111111111  36.8447951082032  37.1607949595411  0  0.991496418424796   
3  9.04168333333334  29.5090743425324  33.1609149651866  0  0.889875154938032   
4  9.99203333333333  28.3149237809555  33.6328585383268  0  0.841882760238438   

            V'O2/kg             PetO2            PetCO2                 ExCO2  \
0  4.42046996694321  115.479326671601  28.7635623488774   -0.0145537951547244   
1  7.63417229349286  111.689054293116  33.3331430668641   -0.0219190689603747   
2  6.04474097554267  117.675559264742  29.9207171560161  -0.00289989981300173   
3  3.87925314003756  115.526557480056  28.6691007319681   -0.0216309094198363   
4  4.53053597793717  109.339321572498  32.0697189407024   -0.0343156864209755   

                 BF WR  Borg  
0             19.16  0  None  
1             12.55  0  None  
2  14.8333333333333  0  None  
3  17.5566666666667  0  None  
4              18.7  0  None
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. I did consider something along those lines just didn't know how to implement it.  To ensure I fully understand what is happening with your code edit - Am I correct in my interpretation that with the `for cell in cells:` loop, the code first test the cell whether it contains `'t'`, if it doesn't `parse` remains false hence the 2nd if statement is never run. Once it reaches the `'t'`, `parse` is set to `true` and since it is never set back to false, every cell from there to the end of the table is read and appended to the list.